# Video element not rendering in IOS devices

Tags: ios, reactjs, video

I have created a react component, within which I've embedded the HTML video tag. The video source is supplied from the local. The video works fine in windows, android, but not in iOS devices.

```
render() {
return (
  <>
    <div className={`${styles.slideItem}`}>
      <video ref={this.props.videoElements[this.props.index]} id="video" playsInline className={`video ${styles.slideImage}`}>
        <source src={this.props.videoHref} type="video/mp4"></source>
      </video>
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

- I've tried adding default attributes of video tag. Even the playsInline doesn't work as expected
- I've tried adding the video URL directly to the code, but it doesn't work as expected.

What am I missing? Is this because of the video format?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This *could* be an issue with the video format. I believe iOS will only play H264-encoded MP4 videos - maybe double check or re-save the video from a video editor? Also, if "the source is supplied from the local" - make sure the iPhone can see the video URL - for example, if it's a local IP on your WiFi, make sure the iPhone is connected to your WiFi network and isn't using Mobile Data.